# Get screen coordinates of selected row in TListView

Tags: delphi, listview

I have a TListView (actually, a custom descendant) display in ViewStyle `vsReport`.  One row is selected.  I would like to get the screen coordinates of that row (or a cell within that row).  Is there any way for me to do this?

(My goal is to display a small form over the list view giving the effect that it dropped down from the selected row).

I am using Delphi 2010 for this particular application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a list view in `vsReport` style I believe the best approach is to use the [`LVM_GETITEMRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761049%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`LVM_GETSUBITEMRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761075%28VS.85%29.aspx) messages.

The VCL does not wrap this functionality up for you but it should not be too difficult to work it out from the MSDN docs.

Whilst it is very simple to use the `TListItem.Position` property exposed by the VCL, as far as I can tell this does not help you obtain the row height or indeed the coordinates of sub items.

**Update**

As NGLN very helpfully points out, the CommCtrl unit does expose [`ListView_GetItemRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774963%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`ListView_GetSubItemRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775004%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which are more convenient to use than the equivalent Windows messages above.

Comment: @Larry For an example of its use: see [Draw own progress bar in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044125/delphi-draw-own-progress-bar-in-list-view/7048062#7048062).

Comment: @NGLN Thanks. Good work. I see your update at the other question and upvoted it. Looks very nice indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  sel: TListItem;
  pnt: TPoint;
begin
  sel := ListView1.Selected;
  if not Assigned(sel) then Exit;
  pnt := ListView1.ClientToScreen(Sel.Position);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Only remaining issue — how to get the height of the row?