# How to color specific List View Item in Delphi?

Tags: delphi-xe5

I'm making a Scheduling System and I want to color some specific Items in the List View. For example, if the current time in the clock is 07:00 AM then the list view would color all the items that has 07:00 AM in it. How would I do this? I really don't know where to start. What i have right now is this,

View Schedule
[image: View Schedule]

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485761/delphi-tlistview-ownerdraw-subitems-change-default-font-its-bold-somehow-aft) for inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the font properties in `OnCustomDrawItem` and `OnCustomDrawSubItem` event handlers. For instance:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
  State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if odd(Item.Index) then begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1CustomDrawSubItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; 
  SubItem: Integer; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if odd(Item.Index) then begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
  end;
end;
```