# ListvVew Progress Indicator

Tags: winapi

I'm looking to custom draw a progress indicator in a listView using standard win32 features, at the minute I can from the NM_CUSTOMDRAW message set a background colour for either 0% or 100% and let windows deal with it or return CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT where I assume I can just fill a portion of the rectangle with colour depending on the % then draw the text on top giving a very basic progress meter but looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044125/delphi-draw-own-progress-bar-in-list-view) there is some really neat effects so I'm wondering if I can achieve anything like that from the basic winapi?

Comment: Anything you see in Windows can be done using the Windows API. In fact, you linked to an answer that is implemented using the Windows API. Now what is your real question?

Comment: I did look through it and checked functions against Microsoft's published ones and DrawElement/GetElementDetails/ThemeServices dont appear.

Comment: Those are wrappers around the UxTheme API. See [Visual Styles Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773178.aspx) for details.

Comment: Thanks for that, the wrapper are in Delph and the wrapper names bear no resemblance to the functions linked to, obviously I can figure out getting fonts and colors and what ThemeServices.ThemesEnabled is but ThemeServices.GetElementDetails / ThemeServices.DrawElement seem to be used the most and its unclear what these wrappers are for so if you or anyone else knows how to achieve the result wanted using standard win32 functions then do tell.

Answer (score 0):

Found an example [here](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/36617-listview-with-progress-bar/) that shows how to do this with the default Windows functions.